# How to change the Text of the browse button in the FileUpload Control (System.Web.UI.WebControls)

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I want to change the Text of the browse button in the FileUpload Control (System.Web.UI.WebControls), instead of the [Browse...] text I want to use [...]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't technically possible for security purposes, so the user cannot be misled.

However, there are a couple of workarounds, although these require working with the raw HTML rather than the .NET server control - take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html for one example.

Answer (score 12):

This is old, but wanted to offer another solution.  You can use jQuery on a standard HTML hyperlink and fire `asp:FileUpload` on click of the HREF.  Just hide the asp:FileUpload at design and doctor the href any way you'd like.

**Link**

```
<a href="#" id="lnkAttachSOW">Attach File</a>
```

**asp:FileUpload**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuSOW" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
```

**Then the jQuery:**

```
$("#lnkAttachSOW").click(function () {
    $("#fuSOW").click();
});
```

Comment: Tried this.  It opens the file dialog box, but it does not save the file in the FileUpload control, so FileUpload.HasFile is always false.

Answer (score 2):

This was how I did it in .NET using AsynchFileUpload and JavaScript...

```html
<asp:Button ID="bUploadPicture" runat="server" Text="Upload Picture"
    OnClientClick="document.getElementById('<%=tFileUpload1.ClientID%>')
        .click();return (false);" />

<div style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
     <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="tFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        OnUploadedComplete="tFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some third party tools provide this option. For example, we use the Telerik Upload control:

[Changing the text of the Browse/select button](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/localization/defaultcs.aspx)

[Example of Rad Upload control](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/remove-text-select-from-the-radupload-browse-button-not-working-well-with-a-custom-skin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use another button and java script to trigger upload browse button, Check this cute and simple solution  [How to change Text in FileUpload control](http://forums.asp.net/t/1121953.aspx)

Hope this help.