# ASP.NET checkbox with custom design

Tags: asp.net, css

Is there any way to change the style ui of the asp.net checkbox.
I tried this:

```
.cabeceraCheckBoxNormal
{
    background:url("../../../ig_res/Default/images/ig_checkbox_off.gif") no-repeat;
    clear:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

but the result is not what i looking for. Because the image appears near the control, and i can see the normal style near the image.
Like this[image]

Edit:
I decided to inspect the html generated and I saw that the ID set on asp checkbox is set to a span, and inside this is the input type checkbox...
so I change the style to this:

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    background:url("../../../ig_res/Default/images/ig_checkbox_off.gif") no-repeat;
    background-position: 3px 2px;
    display:block;
    clear:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

But nothing happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Style/Look of Asp:CheckBox using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112883/change-style-look-of-aspcheckbox-using-css)

Comment: Checkboxes are browser dependent. I tried something as simple as setting borders and found it only worked in a couple of browsers. You can embed the checkbox in a <div> and adorn it.

Comment: Check out the following link [http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css) [Demo](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_custom-forms/legacy/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the best way to get a customised checkbox effect is to add a `<label>` element linked with the checkbox via the `for` attribute. Then hide the checkbox and style the label's `before` pseudo-element as your checkbox instead.

Something like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='myCheck'><label for='myCheck'>Magic!</label>
```

with css:

```
#myCheck { visibility: hidden; }

input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
    display:block;
    content:url('ig_checkbox_off.gif');
    position:relative;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
    content:url('ig_checkbox_on.gif');
}
```

I've created a jsFiddle example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/f9tLemyy/

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can style the checkbox this way, sure - but if you add `runat=server` into the checkbox element (to get it into the server-side code) the image does not get replaced when you click on the checkbox.  With the server having a hold on the control, it only checks/unchecks if the control is visible.