# Is it possible to change the GUI of a checkbox in C#, asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css

I tried searching but can't find any answer to my inquiry.
Here goes.

I want to change the GUI of the checkbox in a CheckBoxList, using asp.net and C#.
For example, I would like to see a ([] unchecked state) ([x]checked state) 
instead of the standard checkbox.

1.Is this doable in C# asp.net, webform?

I've found a tutorial on WPF Styles and Control Templates, but this is all new to me, it
says I have to use MS Silverlight, and coding within the control template of an .xaml file.

2.Is this the only solution?

3.I've noticed how to add tags while writing down my question, can someone tell me how this is implemented? (This is the end result I had in mind)

Due to spam prevention, I can't post images, please see link:
http://i50.tinypic.com/2dvqzc3.jpg

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you want to change how checkbox looks like in html? Then you need to use images instead, checkboxes are browser-specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Answer (score 1):

There could be various ways depending on what and how you want to achieve the effect.
1. CSS
2. Custom control from scratch
3. JQuery

Please check some links provided below

[Change Style/Look of Asp:CheckBox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112883/change-style-look-of-aspcheckbox-using-css)

[ASP.NET checkbox with custom design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899213/asp-net-checkbox-with-custom-design)

http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/

code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox

Hope that helps