# how to change the size of checkbox inside a gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

Is there anyway I can my checkbox fill the whole field in ASP.net gridview ?

[image]

It is going to look something like this

[image]

here is my grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTags" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="True" 
DataSourceID="dsTagsDetailsSelect" >

<Columns>

<asp:CommandField HeaderText="" SelectText="Select" ShowSelectButton="True" ControlStyle-Font-Size="Small">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
</asp:CommandField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add" SortExpression="Added">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbxAdd"
Checked='<%# Eval("Added").ToString()=="1"?true:false  %>' AutoPostBack="true"
OnCheckedChanged="cbxAdd_CheckedChanged" />

</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Occurrence" HeaderText="Count" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Occurrence">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: Would you explain exactly what are you want to do?

Comment: @RabhyaSingh I want the checkbox to be bigger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Style/Look of Asp:CheckBox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112883/change-style-look-of-aspcheckbox-using-css)