# How to change Browse button style in php file uploader

Tags: html, coding-style

I have written following code which generates a browse and upload button.i want to change the default style of browse button.explain me how to do that.

```
<input id="formButton" type="file" name="csv" size="40" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="upload_bulk_trainees" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a file upoad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441341/how-to-style-a-file-upoad)

Comment: This is not possible in a regular way. There are only some "hacks". You may find a solution in [this article on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to replace the file browse button in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108149/what-is-the-best-way-to-replace-the-file-browse-button-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling of `type="file"` fields is extremely limited. Some browsers allow more customization than others - but the general rule is that you better don't expect *any* styling to apply for those fields.

Comment: I want to just increase the space between Browse button and text field ,is that possible

Comment: That's certainly not possible as the field and the button aren't separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. As a security measure, these input controls are kept with a standard look so that users always know what they're interacting with.

Answer (score -1):

either use the style tag

```
<input type="submit" name="upload_bulk_trainees" style="background-color: blue" value="Upload" />
```

or a css class

```
<style type="text/css">
.button {
 background-color: red; 
}
</style>
<input type="submit" name="upload_bulk_trainees" class="button" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: He's talking about the file input's "browse" button - not the submit button.