# ASP.NET Image uploading with Resizing

Tags: asp.net, image, resize, uploading

I have an aspx page which will upload images to server harddisk from client pc

But now i need to change my program in such a way that it would allow me to resize the image while uploading.

Does anyone has any idea on this ? I couldnt not find such properties/methods with Input file server control

Any one there to guide me ?

Comment: How do you "upload" from a "server" to a "client"?

Comment: I suggest using the free and open-source library @ [Image Resizing In .NET](http://imageresizingin.net/) to do this in a single line of code. The other answers are (currently) subject to one or more of the [common pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

Comment: ImageBuilder.Current.Build(HttpPostedFile f, string destinationFilename, new ResizeSettings("maxwidth=200&maxheight=200"));

Comment: [Here is an example of using jCrop](http://nathanaeljones.com/573/combining-jcrop-and-server-side-image-resizing/) with the [ImageResizing.Net libaray](http://imageresizing.net).

Comment: o_O I sense Computer Linguist has some involvement with Image Resizing in .Net

Comment: Yes, that's me, the author. Sorry about forgetting the [full disclosure] tag, normally I don't do that.

Answer (score 16):

Once the file has been saved to the server you can use code like this to resize.  This code will take care of length/width ratio on the resize.

```
public static Bitmap CreateThumbnail(string lcFilename, int lnWidth, int lnHeight)
{

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOut = null;

    try
    {
        Bitmap loBMP = new Bitmap(lcFilename);
        ImageFormat loFormat = loBMP.RawFormat;

        decimal lnRatio;
        int lnNewWidth = 0;
        int lnNewHeight = 0;

        if (loBMP.Width < lnWidth && loBMP.Height < lnHeight)
            return loBMP;

        if (loBMP.Width > loBMP.Height)
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnWidth / loBMP.Width;
            lnNewWidth = lnWidth;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Height * lnRatio;
            lnNewHeight = (int)lnTemp;
        }
        else
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnHeight / loBMP.Height;
            lnNewHeight = lnHeight;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Width * lnRatio;
            lnNewWidth = (int)lnTemp;
        }


        bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);

        loBMP.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    return bmpOut;
}
```

Comment: A bit OT from the question, but how well does this handle low res images? I always end up getting malformed images with mine.

Comment: I have generally been pushing high res images through that code so I can't give you a good answer there.  It's honestly pretty easy to hook into an app and test so you might want to just give it a try, I don't think it will cost you a significant amount of time.

Comment: You're going to get a 50% white (or black) line on the outer border of the image unless you use TileModeXY in an ImageAttributes instance during the DrawImage call..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821261/after-resizing-white-image-gets-gray-border

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to resize "on the fly" since you will need to have the full image before you perform any image transformations. However, after the upload is complete and before you display any results to your user, you can use this basic image resizing method that I've used in a couple of my apps now:

```
   ''' <summary>
   '''    Resize image with GDI+ so that image is nice and clear with required size.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="SourceImage">Image to resize</param>
   ''' <param name="NewHeight">New height to resize to.</param>
   ''' <param name="NewWidth">New width to resize to.</param>
   ''' <returns>Image object resized to new dimensions.</returns>
   ''' <remarks></remarks>
   Public Shared Function ImageResize(ByVal SourceImage As Image, ByVal NewHeight As Int32, ByVal NewWidth As Int32) As Image

      Dim bitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(NewWidth, NewHeight, SourceImage.PixelFormat)

      If bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed Or _
          bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed Or _
          bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed Or _
          bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Undefined Or _
          bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare Or _
          bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555 Or _
          bitmap.PixelFormat = Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale Then
         Throw New NotSupportedException("Pixel format of the image is not supported.")
      End If

      Dim graphicsImage As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)

      graphicsImage.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
      graphicsImage.InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
      graphicsImage.DrawImage(SourceImage, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)
      graphicsImage.Dispose()
      Return bitmap

   End Function
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that image resizing must be done after entire image has been uploaded.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would to allow the user to adjust the size in the browser and then resize the image as described in other answers.

So take a look at this solution which allows you to [upload and crop images with jQuery, jCrop & ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET).

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did in my project, based on your condition ***(height/width)*** you can change the parameter ie(MaxHeight)

```
 public static System.Drawing.Image ScaleImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxHeight)
        {
            var ratio = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    
            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
    
            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            }
            return newImage;
        }
```

---

**On Button click:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblmsg.Text="";
  if ((File1.PostedFile != null) && (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
  {
    Guid uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("LogoImagesFolder") + "\\" + uid+fn;
    try
    {
      string fileExtention = File1.PostedFile.ContentType;
      int fileLenght = File1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
      if (fileExtention == "image/png" || fileExtention == "image/jpeg" || fileExtention == "image/x-png")
      {
        if (fileLenght <= 1048576)
        {
          System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpPostedImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(File1.PostedFile.InputStream);
          System.Drawing.Image objImage = ScaleImage(bmpPostedImage, 81);
          objImage.Save(SaveLocation,ImageFormat.Png);
          lblmsg.Text = "The file has been uploaded.";
          lblmsg.Style.Add("Color", "Green");
         }
         else 
         {
           lblmsg.Text = "Image size cannot be more then 1 MB.";
           lblmsg.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
          }
       }
     else {
             lblmsg.Text = "Invaild Format!";
             lblmsg.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
           }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
       {
          lblmsg.Text= "Error: " + ex.Message;
          lblmsg.Style.Add("Color", "Red");
       }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

How to resize & Upload Image only for .jpg Extensions : 
In upload.aspx page

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="ProductImage" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Upload" />
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProductName" CssClass="form-control" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtProductName" ErrorMessage="The Product name field is required." />
```

And upload.aspx.cs
For resize

```
/// <summary>
/// Created By Rajib Chowdhury Mob. 01766-306306; Web: http://onlineshoping.somee.com/
/// Complete This Page Coding On January 05, 2014
/// Programing C# By Visual Studio 2013 For Web
/// Dot Net Version 4.5
/// Database Virsion MSSQL Server 2005
/// </summary>
        public bool ResizeImageAndUpload(System.IO.FileStream newFile, string folderPathAndFilenameNoExtension, double maxHeight, double maxWidth)
        {
            try
            {
                // Declare variable for the conversion
                float ratio;
                // Create variable to hold the image
                System.Drawing.Image thisImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(newFile);
                // Get height and width of current image
                int width = (int)thisImage.Width;
                int height = (int)thisImage.Height;
                // Ratio and conversion for new size
                if (width > maxWidth)
                {
                    ratio = (float)width / (float)maxWidth;
                    width = (int)(width / ratio);
                    height = (int)(height / ratio);
                }
                // Ratio and conversion for new size
                if (height > maxHeight)
                {
                    ratio = (float)height / (float)maxHeight;
                    height = (int)(height / ratio);
                    width = (int)(width / ratio);
                }
                // Create "blank" image for drawing new image
                Bitmap outImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
                Graphics outGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(outImage);
                SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                // Fill "blank" with new sized image
                outGraphics.FillRectangle(sb, 0, 0, outImage.Width, outImage.Height);
                outGraphics.DrawImage(thisImage, 0, 0, outImage.Width, outImage.Height);
                sb.Dispose();
                outGraphics.Dispose();
                thisImage.Dispose();
                // Save new image as jpg
                outImage.Save(Server.MapPath(folderPathAndFilenameNoExtension + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                outImage.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And Button1_Click Event

```
        string filePath = "~\\Image\\";//your normal image path
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            HttpPostedFile myFile = ProductImage.PostedFile;//Get Slected Image
            int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;//Get slected Image Size
            string myimag = txtProductName.Text;//Get user input image name
            Guid ImageName = Guid.NewGuid();//get unique id
            if ((myFile != null) && (nFileLen > 1048576))
            {
                LabelAddStatus.Text = "minimum size exceed"; //If file image size 1 MB above
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    if (ProductImage.HasFile)
                    {
                        String fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ProductImage.FileName).ToLower();
                        String[] allowedExtensions = { ".jpg" };//Declare For Allowed Extension
                        for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                            {
                                // Read file into a data stream
                                byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];
                                myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);
                                myFile.InputStream.Dispose();
                                // Save the stream to disk as temporary file. make sure the path is unique!
                                System.IO.FileStream newFile
                                        = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath + "_temp.jpg"),
                                                                   System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                                newFile.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);
                                bool success = ResizeImageAndUpload(newFile, filePath + ("thumbs"+myimag + ImageName), 100, 100);//Save image your thumb image path
                                success = ResizeImageAndUpload(newFile, filePath + (myimag + ImageName), 768, 1024);//Save image your normal image path
                                //delete the temp file.
                                newFile.Close();
                                System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(filePath + "_temp.jpg"));
                                LabelAddStatus.Text = "File uploaded.";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                LabelAddStatus.Text = "Unable to accept file type..";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //No Exception Message
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the WebClient class to download the remote image.

After that, then you can resize it...Use DrawImage, not GetThumbnailImage. Make sure you dispose of your bitmap and graphics handles.. (use using{}). Set all quality settings to high.

You might want to take a look at the [source code for my popular image resizer](http://nathanaeljones.com/products/asp-net-image-resizer/) first... It will help you avoid some common trouble areas.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here is another WAY fox!!! i have actually modify the code from You all. HIHI
//First, add one textBox and one FileUpload Control, and a button

//paste this in your code behind file... after public partial class admin : System.Web.UI.Page

    string OriPath;
    string ImageName;

public Size NewImageSize(int OriginalHeight, int OriginalWidth, double FormatSize)
    {
        Size NewSize;
        double tempval;

        if (OriginalHeight > FormatSize && OriginalWidth > FormatSize)
        {
            if (OriginalHeight > OriginalWidth)
                tempval = FormatSize / Convert.ToDouble(OriginalHeight);
            else
                tempval = FormatSize / Convert.ToDouble(OriginalWidth);

            NewSize = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(tempval * OriginalWidth), Convert.ToInt32(tempval * OriginalHeight));
        }
        else
            NewSize = new Size(OriginalWidth, OriginalHeight); return NewSize;
    } 



//Now, On Button click add the folwing code.

if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {
           ImageName = TextBox1.Text+".jpg";


           OriPath = Server.MapPath("pix\\") + ImageName;

           //Gets the Full Path using Filecontrol1 which points to actual location in the hardisk :)

           using (System.Drawing.Image Img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)))
           {
               Size ThumbNailSize = NewImageSize(Img.Height, Img.Width, 800);

               using (System.Drawing.Image ImgThnail = new Bitmap(Img, ThumbNailSize.Width, ThumbNailSize.Height))
               {
                   ImgThnail.Save(OriPath, Img.RawFormat);
                   ImgThnail.Dispose();
               }
               Img.Dispose();
           }
}


//Enjoy. If any problem,, mail me at izacmail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

To resize down a image and get smaller sizes just make the changes below

```
    bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight, **System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb**);

     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
```

as you above a set the imagem to Format24bppRgb PixelFormat.

and when you save the file, you set the ImageFormat also. Like this:

```
bmpOut.Save(PathImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, it does a dandy job for me. But it does not handle low res images well for me. Thankfully I down use to many of them. Just sent it the image `byte[]` and the expected output and you'll be good to go.

```
public static byte[] ResizeImageFile(byte[] imageFile, int targetSize) 
{ 
    using (System.Drawing.Image oldImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageFile))) 
    { 
        Size newSize = CalculateDimensions(oldImage.Size, targetSize); 

        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)) 
        { 
            newImage.SetResolution(oldImage.HorizontalResolution, oldImage.VerticalResolution); 
            using (Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) 
            { 
                canvas.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 
                canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
                canvas.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality; 
                canvas.DrawImage(oldImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), newSize)); 
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(); 
                newImage.Save(m, ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
                return m.GetBuffer(); 
            } 
        } 

    } 
} 

private static Size CalculateDimensions(Size oldSize, int targetSize) 
{ 
    Size newSize = new Size(); 
    if (oldSize.Width > oldSize.Height) 
    { 
        newSize.Width = targetSize; 
        newSize.Height = (int)(oldSize.Height * (float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Width); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        newSize.Width = (int)(oldSize.Width * (float)targetSize / (float)oldSize.Height); 
        newSize.Height = targetSize; 
    } 
    return newSize; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public partial class admin_AddPhoto : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("../picnic");

        if (!Directory.Exists(reportPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("../picnic"));
        }
    }

    protected void PhotoForm_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        FormView uploadForm = sender as FormView;
        FileUpload uploadedFile = uploadForm.FindControl("uploadedFile") as FileUpload;

        if (uploadedFile != null)
        {
            string fileName = uploadedFile.PostedFile.FileName;
            string pathFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            try
            {
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../picnic/") + pathFile);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                //catch exception here
            }

            try
            {
                Bitmap uploadedimage = new Bitmap(uploadedFile.PostedFile.InputStream);

                e.Values["ImageWidth"] = uploadedimage.Width.ToString();
                e.Values["ImageHeight"] = uploadedimage.Height.ToString();
                // Make output File Name
                char[] splitter = { '.' };
                string[] splitFile = pathFile.Split(splitter);
                string OutputFilename = splitFile[0] + "s";

                System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
                System.Drawing.Image thumbImage = uploadedimage.GetThumbnailImage(74, 54, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
                thumbImage.Save(Server.MapPath("../picnic/") + OutputFilename + ".jpg");
                e.Values["Thumbnail"] = "./picnic/" + OutputFilename + ".jpg";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //catch exception here
            }

            e.Values["Pic"] = "./picnic/" + pathFile;
            e.Values["Url"] = "./picnic/" + pathFile;
            e.Values["dateEntered"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }

    public bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This uses a FileUpload and a FormView to insert. Then I use the [GetThumnailImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) method provided in System.Drawing.Imaging. You can enter any Width and Height values and it will shrink/stretch accordingly.

```
uploadedimage.GetThumbnailImage(W, H, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could resize before sending to the server using an ActiveX control.  There is a free ASP.net image uploading component (I believe this is the same one that Facebook actually uses) available here:

http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst2145_Image-Uploader-ASPNET-Control.aspx

Let me know if it works, I am thinking about implementing it in my projects here at work.

Edit:  Looks like the wrapper for the object is free, however the actual component itself is going to run you about $200.  I confirmed it is the same component Facebook is using though.

Answer (score 0):

The uploading of the image file is performed by ASP.NET 4.0 Client Callbacks. If you are not familiar with client callbacks then I suggest that you take a look at ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit AsyncFileUpload Control without page refresh or PostBack in ASP.Net Web Page or ASP.Net AJAX Update Panel. The callback is fired as soon as the file is selected by the user using the file field control.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ResizeImageAndSave(int Width, int Height, string imageUrl, string destPath)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageUrl);
 double widthRatio = (double)fullSizeImg.Width / (double)Width;
  double heightRatio = (double)fullSizeImg.Height / (double)Height;
  double ratio = Math.Max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
 int newWidth = (int)(fullSizeImg.Width / ratio);
 int newHeight = (int)(fullSizeImg.Height / ratio);
        //System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort dummyCallBack = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        System.Drawing.Image thumbNailImg = fullSizeImg.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero);
 //DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Now;
 //String MyString = MyDate.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss") + imageUrl.Substring(imageUrl.LastIndexOf("."));
 thumbNailImg.Save(destPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 thumbNailImg.Dispose();
        return "";
    }
    public bool ThumbnailCallback() { return false; }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for taking the time to answer. Consider also adding some explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void ResizeImage(FileUpload fileUpload)
{
    // First we check to see if the user has selected a file
    if (fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        // Find the fileUpload control
        string filename = fileUpload.FileName;

        // Check if the directory we want the image uploaded to actually exists or not
        if (!Directory.Exists(MapPath(@"Uploaded-Files")))
        {
            // If it doesn't then we just create it before going any further
            Directory.CreateDirectory(MapPath(@"Uploaded-Files"));
        }
        // Specify the upload directory
        string directory = Server.MapPath(@"Uploaded-Files\");

        // Create a bitmap of the content of the fileUpload control in memory
        Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(fileUpload.FileContent);

        // Calculate the new image dimensions
        int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
        int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
        int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
        int newWidth = 100;
        int newHeight = newWidth / sngRatio;

        // Create a new bitmap which will hold the previous resized bitmap
        Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);

        // Create a graphic based on the new bitmap
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
        // Set the properties for the new graphic file
        oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 
        oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Draw the new graphic based on the resized bitmap
        oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        // Save the new graphic file to the server
        newBMP.Save(directory + "tn_" + filename);

        // Once finished with the bitmap objects, we deallocate them.
        originalBMP.Dispose();
        newBMP.Dispose();
        oGraphics.Dispose();

        // Write a message to inform the user all is OK
        label.Text = "File Name: <b style='color: red;'>" + filename + "</b><br>";
        label.Text += "Content Type: <b style='color: red;'>" + fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType + "</b><br>";
        label.Text += "File Size: <b style='color: red;'>" + fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString() + "</b>";

        // Display the image to the user
        Image1.Visible = true;
        Image1.ImageUrl = @"Uploaded-Files/tn_" + filename;
    }
    else
    {
        label.Text = "No file uploaded!";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the added value compared to other answers?