# given Image resize and save the resize image

Tags: c#

I want to re-size an user input picture and want to save the resize image in a folder. Please help me to do this task

Comment: You can find on StackOverflow ( by Google )

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254419/asp-net-image-uploading-with-resizing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87753/resizing-an-image-without-losing-any-quality

Answer (score 0):

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing  this is good article for you