# Classic ASP/ASP.net multifile upload and resize in two different sizes

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I work on a server that can run both classic ASP and ASP.net but I don't want/can't use components.
I need the user of my site to upload multiple images at once, these images have to be saved in two different directories and with two different dimensions.
I searched the web for the last two weeks but I can't find anything doing all this.
Can you help me?

Thanks in advance,
Alessia

Answer (score 0):

[This is a Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441925/how-to-choose-multiple-files-using-file-upload-control) showing how to upload multiple files at once

To save the files in two different directories, in the example on that post, where the file is saved, simply duplicate the following call with the `filepath` to your two directories

```
 userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" +    Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));
```

Once you've got your images uploaded, [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254419/asp-net-image-uploading-with-resizing) has a couple of examples of image resizing.

Although some 3rd party components might make some of this a little easier to implement, you shouldn't need to use any at all, and there are plenty of examples around of how to achieve everything you're after just using .net libraries.

Hope this is all of some use, or at least helps you find some other resources that do the trick for you.