# How to Re-size image on File Upload

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to resize the image that is being uploaded using FileUpload control in ASP.net using VB.NET

I am using a file upload code:

```
If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
    Dim theFileName As String = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), newfile)
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(theFileName)
End If
```

How do I resize the image to width:270px height:307px?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Image uploading with Resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254419/asp-net-image-uploading-with-resizing)

Comment: Duplicate from 6 years ago? and that is in C#

Comment: Yes, not surprisingly this question has been asked before, and not just on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What image are you referring to?

Comment: @ChicagoMike I am trying to resize the image that is being uploaded using FileUpload control in asp.net using VB.NET

Comment: @BillyHen http://converter.telerik.com/ problem fixed:)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hope this help :

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
Dim newImage = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
Using g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
    g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I apply this to the FileUpload1?