# change label on asp fileupload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using a asp fileUpload control, and was wondering if it is possible to change the lable on the button from the default "Browse".

```
 <span class="spanText">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Width="280px"  />
        </span>
```

From what i can read, there donesn't seem to be an easyway, unless I dig into its controls colection.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94316/how-to-change-the-text-of-the-browse-button-in-the-fileupload-control-system-web

Comment: thanks for that.  So its possible but not "Clean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out-of-the-box. "Browse" is really a convention and what people expect when browsing to a file on their own machine. You'd have to have a compelling reason to go to the trouble of changing it - and that would be a hack at best.